# NameError: name '_htmlparser' is not defined: When trying to use BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup in my programme but having major issues. I have spent 5+hours troubleshooting but can't progress pass this error message.

I am using Python3 v3.8.3 and have pip installed bs4 and BeautifulSoup4

The bs4 folder is in the same folder as my programme and have used the import statement

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The full trace back error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FIBA.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import beautifulsoup
  File "/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 303, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "/Users/adamsewell/Desktop/Python/Programmes/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 41, in <module>
    class BeautifulSoupHTMLParser(_htmlparser):
NameError: name '_htmlparser' is not defined
```

I am really new to programming so any help would be great as hit a brick wall, thank you

Comment: from html.parser import HTMLParser Import this package

Comment: thank you for your response, there seemed to be lots of issues / dugs so ending up uninstalling BeautifulSoup in library and using pip and re-installed.  Seems to be ok